# Compositing transparency challenge. Particle not part of alpha?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency

Hey Wicked Smaht people!
I have been working on a project that will be super imposed, in photoshop, over another image.

So, I have been trying to composite it so that the background is transparent.

And, it renders transparent, so I know that part is working.

However, whenever I save it as a png or tiff (RGBa), either thru the file output or by saving in the render result window, it cuts of my sparks!

It appears that the alpha channel is actually the depth channel.

How do I get the sparks to stay?

Here's a screen shot of the render results

[image: render result window]

However the saved file looks like this.

[image: actual png reduced in size]

And here is my composite node set up.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: This is driving me nuts!]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I never did get an answer on this one. I did find a work around, though.

I turned on the Emit pass, put it through the glare node and output it as a png. There was no transparency in the file, but, since the background rendered black, I was able to bring it into photoshop and knock the black out.

I also rendered the girder/laser layer and placed it under the emit layer.

There must be a way to do the composite in blender.

If you know it, please add your answer below.

Here's the composite output I was using.

[image: Final composite nodes]

And, here is the photoshop composite in progress. The green layer was added so I could see what the sparks would look like. It was replaced by another background image before it went to the client.

Still looking for the proper way to do this in Blender...

[image: final in progress]

Comment: The answer is the shit file format known as PNG. Encode to EXR and you’ll get your emissions without occlusion back.